# virtualbox to qemu but results in no bootable device qemu

Tags: kvm-virtualization, virtualbox, libvirt, qemu, vagrant

I use vagrant to create my development vm. I exported the vmdk to vdi, and then convert the vdi to img.

```
cd virtualbox_dir/test_vm
VBoxManage clonehd test_vm.vmdk raw.vdi
0% ..... 100%
qemu-img convert raw.vdi raw.img
virsh create testvm.xml
```

But I am getting `no bootable device`.

[image]

In my XML, the boot device is set to `hd`. I basically copy from an existing, running XMK. I am taking over this work from a previous lab student so it isn't clear to me how he manage to produce the vm before.

Any idea what could go wrong? Thanks.

Here is the XML file

```
<domain type='kvm'>
  <name>Test</name>
  <memory>4194304</memory>
  <currentMemory>4194304</currentMemory>
  <vcpu>2</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='rhel5.4.0'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <pae/>
  </features>
  <clock offset='utc'>
    <timer name='pit' tickpolicy='delay'/>
  </clock>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>restart</on_crash>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/libexec/qemu-kvm</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none'/>
      <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/raw.img'/>
      <target dev='hda' bus='ide'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <target dev='hdc' bus='ide'/>
      <readonly/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='1' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='ide' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <source bridge='br0'/>
    </interface>
    <serial type='pty'>
      <target port='0'/>
    </serial>
    <console type='pty'>
      <target port='0'/>
    </console>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
    <graphics type='vnc' port='-1' autoport='yes' keymap='en-us'/>
    <sound model='ac97'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </sound>
    <video>
      <model type='cirrus' vram='9216' heads='1'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
    </video>
  </devices>
</domain>
```

Comment: 1.1 GB is a _very small_ hard drive image. If that isn't approximately the right size, then something went wrong in the conversion.

Comment: @MichaelHampton It has no software in it. It's Ubuntu 12.04 with user changed. Not sure if that answer your doubt :( maybe it did. Thanks !

Comment: @MichaelHampton The ova is only 300MB, by the way.

Comment: I don't mean to spam you, but the vmdk itself is only 1.1GB if I did the math right (1010368512 from ls).